# mongoDB count array elements in deep nested array objects

Tags: mongodb

I am attempting to prepare aggregation query for faster deep nested elements count , collection is pretty big(100M docs / 1TB / mongodb 4.4) so any $unwind's make the task very slow ,  please, advice if there is any option to use $reduce / $filter or other faster option:

Example document:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5c05984246a0201286d4b57a"),
f: "x",
"_a": [
  {
    "_onlineStore": {}
  },
  {
    "_p": [
      {
        "pid": 1,
        "s": {
          "a": {
            "t": [
              {
                id: 1,
                "dateP": "20200-09-20",
                lang: "EN"
              },
              {
                id: 2,
                "dateP": "20200-09-20",
                lang: "En"
              }
            ]
          },
          "c": {
            "t": [
              {
                id: 3,
                lang: "en"
              },
              {
                id: 4,
                lang: "En"
              },
              {
                id: 5,
                "dateP": "20300-09-23"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        h: "Some data"
      }
      ]
    }
   ]
  }
```

I need to count number of "_a[]._p[]._s.c.t[]" array elements  where lang: $in:["En","en" ,"EN","En","eN"]

Note elements under "_a._p._s.a.t" or "_a._p._s.d.t" shall not be included in the count ...

Expected result 1:

```
   { count:2}
```

Expected result 2:

```
        {
          id: 3,
          lang: "en"
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          lang: "En"
        }
```

Please, advice?

Thanks

[1.Extended example that need to be fixed playground (count expected to be 8)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kXg6Xy7k92y)

Here is my unwind version , but for big collection it looks pretty expensive:

[2. Playground unwind version ( expensive )](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Fz-tzmSraIe)

Comment: Maybe these [Demo 1](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FfHLxZHLSFp) and [Demo 2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TFR3HYpaUcJ) meet your needs?

Comment: What is the desired output for your extended mongoplayground.net example?

Comment: @rickhg12hs for extended example count is 4   , Yong: Demo 1 and Demo 2 seems to count just the docs , I need to count the t's inside _a._p._s_c

Comment: Noted. I revise the demo: [Demo 1](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zcT_wo3FhLl) & [Demo 2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8jwvP6vakHC)

Comment: This [mongoplayground.net example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/teOH5t_9uWE) perhaps?  Looks like you're spoiled with choices.  :-)

Comment: I think in Demo 2, the regex should use "^en$" to represent the matching of the exact "en" word, avoid match of partial string in previous Demo 2 link.

Comment: small correction , missed to add that _p is array : https://mongoplayground.net/p/YP6sei3ioTT

Comment: Maybe one more nested $reduce or $filter need to be added here , but not very sure how: https://mongoplayground.net/p/kXg6Xy7k92y

Comment: Just for the records :  @nimrod serok solved my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75260277/mongodb-count-deeply-nested-array-elements-filtered-by-and-condition/75266545#75266545

Answer (score 0):

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([
{
    $project: {
        count: {
            $size: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$_a._p.s.t",
                    as: "t",
                    cond: { $ne: ["$$t", null] }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

])

Comment: Hi @mohamed ouf , thanks for your answer , but it seems not working : https://mongoplayground.net/p/bXUywJp8JQm    ( it counts 2x2 , but need to be 8 )