# mongoDB count deeply nested array elements filtered by and condition

Tags: mongodb

I am attempting to count elements in 3x nested array , I have some progress , but struggling to filter based on lang:"EN" condition inside the 2x $reduced 1x filter :

Here is example document:

```
 {
    "_id": ObjectId("5c05984246a0201286d4b57a"),
 f: "x",
"_a": [
  {
    "_onlineStore": {}
  },
  {
    "_p": [
      {
        "pid": 1,
        "s": {
          "a": {
            "t": [
              {
                id: 1,
                "dateP": "20200-09-20",
                lang: "EN"
              },
              {
                id: 2,
                "dateP": "20200-09-20",
                lang: "En"
              }
            ]
          },
          "c": {
            "t": [
              {
                id: 3,
                lang: "en"
              },
              {
                id: 4,
                lang: "En"
              },
              {
                id: 5,
                "dateP": "20300-09-23"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        h: "Some data"
      }
    ]
  }]
 }
```

And here is my attempt ( just need to filter only the elements with lang:"EN"

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
$project: {
  res: {
    $reduce: {
      input: "$_a",
      initialValue: [],
      in: {
        $concatArrays: [
          "$$value",
          {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                "$eq": [
                  {
                    "$type": "$$this._p"
                  },
                  "array"
                ]
              },
              "then": {
                $reduce: {
                  input: "$$this._p",
                  initialValue: [],
                  in: {
                    $concatArrays: [
                      "$$value",
                      {
                        "$filter": {
                          "input": {
                            "$objectToArray": "$$this.s"
                          },
                          "as": "f",
                          "cond": {
                            "$eq": [
                              "$$f.k",
                              "c"
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              },
              "else": []
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
 }
},
{
  $unwind: "$res"
},
{
  $unwind: "$res.v.t"
},
  {
    $count: "Total"
  }
])
```

I need to count all _a[]._p[].s.c.t[]  where lang:"EN","en","En"  , note at object s there is multiple nested elements c , a , d , etc , only the c need to be counted where lang:"EN"  , I managed to filter only the "c" but struggling to add the lang:"EN","en","En" inside the $filter.cond , can anybody help here?

Expected playground output is:

```
{count:7}
```

I can add final $match condition and clear the lang:EN , but I am wondering if there is better option to be done inside the reduce/reduce/objectToArray/cond  and avoid the $unwind's?

[Playgorund](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TZGEOwBYOW3)

Comment: [Here's](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CdY5f7gJCdg) just another layer of `"$reduce"` to handle `_p` being an array.

Comment: @rickhg12hs : Thanks alot for the suggestion , please add as an answer , came accross the following final solution: https://mongoplayground.net/p/x9ScwLA5GAq

Comment: Cool!  You should add yours as an answer.

Comment: the trick with the project/set was the inspiring idea so please , add the answer :) , unless there is no other optimal option ...

Comment: Ha!  The _"fred"_  stage was used so I could look at the structure by using mongoplayground's "Stage by stage output".  I just forgot to remove it later.  When I saw your _"fred"_ stage I thought we might be distant cousins sharing a common temp variable naming gene.  :-)

Comment: If I did post an answer, I wouldn't include the _"fred"_ stage since it serves no purpose there really.  My answer isn't very inspiring - it just grinds through some `"$reduce"`s, etc.  Your answer demonstrates how an identified deeply nested array/object can be brought to the surface.  For super large structures and/or large collections, I'm not sure what the performance would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option to avoid `$unwind` is:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {"_a._p.s.c.t": {$elemMatch: {lang: {$in:  ["EN", "En", "en"]}}}}},
  {$project: {
      res: {$reduce: {
          input: "$_a._p.s.c.t",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {$concatArrays: ["$$value", "$$this"]}
        }}
  }},
  {$project: {
        res: {$reduce: {
          input: "$res",
          initialValue: 0,
          in: {$sum: [
              "$$value",
              {$size: {$filter: {
                    input: "$$this",
                    as: "inner",
                    cond: {$in: ["$$inner.lang", ["EN", "En", "en"]]}
              }}}
          ]}
      }}
  }},
  {$group: {_id: 0, count: {$sum: "$res"}}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TunOUOP0wEG)

Comment: But now when I'm looking on @rickhg12hs's answer it looks very similar. rickhg12hs, Please post your answer as an answer, and I'll vote for it

Comment: @nimrodserok : Thanks ! Tested on the real collection and is working as expected!   Not sure why but the one from rickhh12hs ( not the fred one ) is giving me: The argument to $size must be an array, but was of type: null ...